# How to realize meteor like real-time features in ember.js and ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, meteor, ember-data

I'm evaluating ember.js with ember-data and meteor for a single-page web app.
So far my conclusion is that meteor can best be compared with a combination of ember.s and ember data while ember data takes the role of minimongo.
I really like the real-time sync of data with minimongo in meteor and would like to see this feature in ember.js. My question is whether we will see this or whether this is totally out of scope? Maybe there is a secondary lib or project which could be plugged in to have such functionality?
The question is pretty specific but I think for this topic any broader scoped contribution can be valuable.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An ember-data store can be fed by many sources via adapters, one of which could certainly connect with web sockets. I prefer ember's clean separation of store from adapter to meteor's approach, which seems to require tighter coupling between client / server (I may be wrong here - I admittedly don't have experience with meteor).

You might want to check out Paul Chavard's (@tchak) [colors-demo](https://github.com/tchak/colors-demo), a rails / ember / web sockets app that replicates the original Meteor demo. It's a quick proof-of-concept app and may be a bit outdated at this point, but it certainly shows that real-time ember apps are possible.